# Create list in PL/SQL instead of subquery

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, subquery, proc

I need to bring data from some distance server, for connection I use DB Link in Oracle. A simple select query took around 6 seconds to be executed.

Here is sample of taking data by some block(around 20 row), average execution time is around 25 seconds :

```
select * from external_table et where et.pk in 
 (select lt.pk from local_table lt where condition)
```

For calling queries I use services written in pro*c(T-Max). First I receive data from local table (took maybe 20ms) and create list into some varchar variable `local_list` using pro*c(for and string operation). This list contains directly data f.e.: `('001','002',...,'003','020')`
And then I execute query for retrieving data from external table

```
select * from external_table et where et.pk in **local_list**
```

Result is much faster than original query (6 seconds).

It worked well for long time, but now I need to create some batch job directly in db to do this using PL/SQL procedure. Is there some way how to create this kind list in PL/SQL? Or speed up original retrieving query?

Answer (score 1):

As your local table has the keys you are interested in from the external table, I would suggest just using a standard join:

```
SELECT * 
     FROM EXTERNAL_TABLE ET
     INNER JOIN LOCAL_TABLE LT
      ON ET.PK = LT.PK
 WHERE (<put any criteria in here for your local table>);
```

alternatively:

```
SELECT * 
     FROM EXTERNAL_TABLE ET LOCAL_TABLE LT          
 WHERE ET.PK = LT.PK AND
       (<put any other criteria in here for your local table>);
```

I'm not sure that a subquery is helping much in this case.

Answer (score 0):

join could help speed was same, but finally i found solution for my problem, dynamic sql.

```
select 'SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_TABLE ET WHERE ET.PK IN '
INTO SELECT QUERY FROM DUAL;  
PK_LIST:='('    
 FOR C_LIST IN(    
  SELECT PK FROM local_table where some_condition)    
 LOOP    
  if PK_LIST= '(' THEN
   SELECT PK_LIST||'''' ||C_LIST.PK|| ''''    
    INTO PK_LIST   
   FROM DUAL;   
  ELSE    
   SELECT PK_LIST||',''' ||C_LIST.PK|| ''''   
     INTO PK_LIST    
     FROM DUAL;   
  END IF ;   
 END LOOP;
SELECT PK_LIST||')'  
  INTO PK_LIST   
  FROM DUAL;            
SELECT SELECT_QUERY || PK_LIST    
  INTO MAIN_QUERY   
  FROM DUAL;     
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE MAIN_QUERY;
```

sorry for formatting but i am in hurry,
result is 2 - 4 second :), that is better then i expected.
i saw somewhere information about not to use dynamic sql, but i got no other option. I save lot of time in production :)
i you have some other recommendation, please write it
thanks